# Why doesn't Mathemtica and Wolfram Alpha give the same answer

Tags: equation-solving

In Mathematica,

```
Solve[ 12 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 1 == 0]
```

gives

```
{{x -> Root[-1 + 12 #^2 + 12 #^3& , 1, 0]}, {x -> 
 Root[-1 + 12 #^2 + 12 #^3& , 2, 0]}, {x -> 
 Root[-1 + 12 #^2 + 12 #^3& , 3, 0]}}
```

but

```
== Solve 12x^3+12x^2-1=0
```

gives the solutions in exact form. I don't understand why Mathematica does not give the same answer as Wolfram Alpha. Any explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica gives the same exact results only in a different representation using [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions.

```
sol = Solve[12 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 1 == 0]
```

[image]

Verifying that these are the solutions

```
12 x^3 + 12 x^2 - 1 == 0 /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

If you prefer to see the radical representation use [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html)

```
sol // ToRadicals // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: With the setting `Cubics -> True`, `Solve[]` will return Cardano-type solutions.